# django-objects tag filter

Tags: django, object, filter

I'm calling a post.objects.all object on my html page. on the same page last-post. I made a filter for this but I get an error. calling the last 3 posts I want to do

I can't type .objects.order_by () because it's probably an object.

I can't type .objects.order_by () because it's probably an object.

```
    views.py :
   def post_index(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    category = Category.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        post_list = post_list.filter(
            Q(post_title__icontains=query) |
            Q(post_content__icontains=query) |
            Q(post_date__date=query) 
        ).distinct()

    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 18)  # Show 5 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'category':category,
    }
    return render(request, "post/post-list.html", context)
    html:

        {%for post in posts|lasted %}

    filter.py

            @register.filter
        def lasted(post):


            return post.objects.order_by('post_date')[:3]


    AttributeError at /post/index/
    'Page' object has no attribute 'objects'
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/index/
    Django Version: 2.2.7
    Exception Type: AttributeError
    Exception Value:    
    'Page' object has no attribute 'objects'
    Exception Location: C:\Users\Barbaros\Desktop\All\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaultfilters.py in lasted, line 73
    Python Executable:  C:\Users\Barbaros\Desktop\All\env\Scripts\python.exe
    Python Version: 3.7.4
    Python Path:    
    ['C:\\Users\\Barbaros\\Desktop\\All',
     'C:\\Users\\Barbaros\\Desktop\\All\\env\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
     'C:\\Users\\Barbaros\\Desktop\\All\\env\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Users\\Barbaros\\Desktop\\All\\env\\lib',
     'C:\\Users\\Barbaros\\Desktop\\All\\env\\Scripts',
     'c:\\users\\barbaros\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\Lib',
     'c:\\users\\barbaros\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Users\\Barbaros\\Desktop\\All\\env',
     'C:\\Users\\Barbaros\\Desktop\\All\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
    Server time:    Fri, 22 Nov 2019 20:36:41 +0000
```

Comment: You already have got posts queryset in your views.py. and not need in filter.py call the `objects`. Try just `return post.order_by('post_date')[:3]`

Comment: dont try : 'Page' object has no attribute 'order_by'

Comment: I thought you changed code in the question after yestarday comment. Now try `{%for post in posts.object_list|lasted %}` and order its in filter as list by `sort`(or `sorted`) vs key argument(key is func for comparision `post_date`). Or try to pass to Paginator sorted queryset `Paginator(post_list.order_by('...'),18)` without using custom filter then

Answer (score 0):

I thought you changed code in the question after yestarday comment. Now try {%for post in posts.object_list|lasted %} and order its in filter as list by sort(or sorted) vs key argument(key is func for comparision post_date). Or try to pass to Paginator sorted queryset Paginator(post_list.order_by('...'),18) without using custom filter then – Александр 18 hours